# How to repair my WSL Ubuntu after uninstalling my active terminal emulator?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used zsh fort some time now and I wanted to try out the kitty terminal emulator, but I forgot to set another one beforehand the uninstallation of zsh. Now my ubuntu throws an error every time I try to launch it:

```
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\braga\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/HCS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\braga\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/HCS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Failed to attach disk 'C:\Users\braga\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx' to WSL2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/MountVhd/HCS/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Press any key to continue...
```

I've tried reinstalling ubuntu but it didn't work out. How can i fix this?

Comment: Does the VHDD actually exist?